# customize BindingResult fieldError message

Tags: java, spring

i'm trying to customize BindingResult error message when it finds a field error while validating input.

i'm currently doing this

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Add an Employee")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void addEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeDto e, BindingResult bindingResult) {
            if (bindingResult.hasFieldErrors()) {
                List bindingErrors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
                for (FieldError error : bindingErrors) {
                    String field = error.getField();
                    bindingResult.rejectValue(field, "Format invalide! vous devez respecter specs" + field);

                }
            }

            else {
                // Employee employee = new Employee();
                ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
                Employee employee = modelMapper.map(e, Employee.class);

                employeeRepository.save(employee);
            }
        }
```

and i have this in my dto

```
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
        // @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
        // @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](19|20)$")
        private Date birthDate;
```

my message is not seen i'm always getting the default message !